# Create array based on object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'd like to use an object to configure some settings for an app. My idea is to start with this:

```
var obj = {
    property_one: 3;
    property_two: 2;
    property_three: 1;
}
```

And I would like to end up with this:

```
var array = [
    'property_one','property_one','property_one',
    'property_two','property_two',
    'property_three'
]
```

My current solution is to do this for each property:

```
function theConstructor(){
    for(i=1; i <= obj.property_one; i++){
        this.array.push('property_one');
    };
    for(i=1; i <= obj.property_two; i++){
        this.array.push('property_two');
    };
    for(i=1; i <= obj.property_two; i++){
        this.array.push('property_two');
    };
}
```

But this gets tedious, because I might have many properties, and these might change as the app evolves.

I know I can loop through `object`'s properties like this:

```
for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    array.push(key);
  }
}
```

But this will push the value to the array, not the key (as a string). Any ideas about how I can do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function theConstructor(){
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      for(var i=1; i <= obj[key]; i++){
        this.array.push(key);
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You missed to declare variable `i`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, don't know how I didn't see this looking back!

Answer (score 1):

Using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var obj = {
  property_one: 3,
  property_two: 2,
  property_three: 1
};

var resultArray = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(result, curItem) {
  for (var index = 0; index < obj[curItem]; index++) {
    result.push(curItem);
  }
  return result;
}, []);

document.write(JSON.stringify(resultArray));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a very elegant solution.